# Fixing a mangled master branch in fork

Tags: git, github

I was working on a pull request for an open source project, but I accidentally committed my changes to my local `master` branch. Without thinking it over hard enough, I just went ahead and pushed it to my origin and submitted my master branch as a PR. Then I later pulled the upstream master into my master so I could fix merge conflicts to keep my PR up to date. Since then, more commits have been made to upstream.

So now I have:

```
upstream master: A - B - C ... H - I - J

my fork master:  A - B - X - Y
```

Where X was the first version of my PR, and Y is a merge of C-H onto X.

So now my fork is in quite a tangle. I can't work on unrelated PRs without starting a branch before B and then pulling upstream master into that branch each time. And if my original PR is rejected or takes a year to get feedback on, I'll be stuck in this state indefinitely.

Are there any options for fixing this? Do I have to nuke my PR and my X and Y commits and redo them manually (and if so, how)? Or can I salvage my PR somehow and get my master branch back in sync with upstream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do in this scenario looks a bit like this:

First, check out a new branch from your existing `master`:

```
git checkout -b master-preserve
```

Then, reset your `master` to `upstream/master`:

```
git checkout master
git fetch upstream
git reset --hard upstream/master
```

Now, create *another* branch:

```
git checkout -b upstream-with-commits
```

And cherry-pick `X` and `Y` onto it:

```
git cherry-pick X Y # Replace with the appropriate commit IDs
```

Then push this branch to your fork, nuke the existing PR, and open a new one against `upstream-with-commits`. To get your fork's `master` back in order, do:

```
git checkout master
git push -f origin HEAD
```

`git push -f` will force a push, and overwrite any history in `origin/master`. Be warned that, if other people have cloned from your fork, it may cause problems for them.

Oh, and don't forget to delete `master-preserve`:

```
git branch -D master-preserve
```

Once you've `cherry-pick`ed from it, it's no longer necessary.

Comment: This worked beautifully. Everybody upvote this for me, since I can only do it once. :) One nice thing with Github...it automatically closed the original PR for me once I force-pushed the fixed master branch.

Comment: Thanks for fixing my typo. Didn't notice I'd accidentally dropped that `-b` in there. :)